# High current shift register source (mic5891 alternative)

Tags: current-source, shift-register, high-side

I'm trying to control 60 loads (solenoid valve with integrated control circuit,12v dc) requiring high side 50mA source current control signal using an MCU (3.3v)

I need to control them individually so I decided to use daisy chained shift registers.
Looking online, I found mic5891, it seems to be the perfect component for my application, but then I realized it is out off stock everywhere.

So, now I'm looking for a "high current" shift register source (an alternative to mic5891) or a simple (as few components as possible) alternative solution.

Comment: Using motor driver chips with SPI input and multiple half bridge outputs can be a fallback solution.

Answer (score 1):

[TPIC6C596](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpic6c596.pdf), or 595, or NPIC will give you 8 high voltage open drain outputs (active low).

I guess you could add 8x cheap PNPs or PMOS and resistors per chip to make it active high...

Comment: Adding pnp transistor or p- MOSFET is a valid solution, but introduce a lot of variable that for now I'm not comfortable with them (select the right part and resistors). Mic5891 was a great single chip solution....

Comment: Reading some online discussion, I understand that in order to use a pnp transistor with a load voltage higher that MCU supply voltage (my case), it is necessary to use an additional npn transistor, two or three resistors...too much components....